# How to model the state space matrix of a pendulum?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, control-engineering, control-theory, dynamics, kinematics

Here's an image of the problem:
[image]

I'm trying to put the following problem in matrix form (state space) but I don't know how would I put -(g/L)sin(x1) in the A matrix since the x1 value is inside the sin() wave.

Thanks!

Comment: What you may be referring is the state space representation of a linear system where the coefficients can be separated from the state variables. $\dot x = A x$. Your system is a non linear system. It cannot be represented in this format. It can be linearised. The linear approximation of the system can be brought into the form you need.

Comment: hint:  sin(x) ≈ x  ,    for small x

Comment: [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/527216/238590) is an answer I wrote which shows linearisation steps, in case you want to go that way.

Comment: if it's a small angle you can put -g/l in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the Taylor series expansion

$$\sin \left(x_1\right) = x_1-\frac{x_1^3}{6}+O\left(x_1^4\right)$$

As $x_1$ gets further away from 0, the correctness of the approximation and that of the linear model with $\sin \left(x_1\right) \approx x_1 $ decreases.

[image]